# Georeferencing image in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a problem with projection.

When I try to georeference an image in QGIS, I set up CRS WGS 84 Pseudo Mercator (EPSG: 3857).

That info appears in georeference settings and it is also my default projection system.

When I start georeferencing, the final raster comes with a USER 100004 CRS.

I tried to change it but when I open tiff file again in properties is still USER CRS.

[image: SRS TARGET]

[image: After I georeference]

Comment: When you start to georeference a map it should have no CRS, when you finish the georeference (assuming you've followed https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html) the CRS specified in the georeferencer transformation should be applied.. what have you entered there in target SRS?

Comment: It doesn't have any CRS. In transformstion settings I set SRS to epgs 3857 wgs84 pseudo mercator. After I start georeference the image, as I said, in properties of the resulting raster image I have something else in the CRS field.

Comment: Shouldn't that be EPSG:3857 in *target SRS*? Can you grab a screen shot of your Transformation Settings dialog and include it in your question?

Comment: I attached 2 images. First is before I start georeference, when I choose SRS Target and second one is the result. Do you have any ideea why?

Comment: If you add an Openstreetmap background, is the raster on the right spot? If yes, you can safely assign EPSG:3857 to it and everything should be fine.

Comment: I have a satellite tile for background and it is ok for me. But a client said  that he needed to set the Crs before  "upload" the raster to be on the right spot. So i think that for other users it might be a problem.

Comment: Does it help to save to a new filename, or use gdal_translate with `-a_srs`?

Comment: I found a way that I use it right now, but it takes a little time in plus, a few seconds to minutes, depends by size of the map. I right click on the raster->save as and then i set up WGS84  EPSG:3857.  I wanted to "get" the SRS Target from first step.